# Use target_link_libraries to libraries not start with lib*

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link my program(hello) with a special library(/path/abc.so) that not starts with 'lib'.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executables(hello hello.c)

target_link_libraries(hello /path/abc.so)
```

It works fine, but is there any other way to avoid this full path(/path/abc.so) things?
I don't want to make symlink of abc.so or modify abc.so itself.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your best option is not to link directly the library, but use imported targets:
You can have your library target as

```
add_library(ABC SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ABC PROPERTIES
            IMPORTED_LOCATION path/to/library/abc.so
            INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES path/to/include
            )
```

Then you can link it as a target:

```
target_link_libraries(hello ABC)
```

The next step would be to have a library find module, or config module, so you don't define full path in your CMakeLists.txt, but search for the library, or just include a .cmake file with all of the paths.

Have a look [HERE](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries) and [HERE](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets)

Comment: However there are still full path things that could be change. Maybe, what i am trying to do is modifying system settings(ld.so.conf?) to find the libraries not starts with lib. Thanks for your answer.